# Unable to install Worklight for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm trying to install IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio in Eclipse Juno SR2.
But, each time I get the following error

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.imp.webtools.dojo.library.distributions,2.0.400.v20160331_0555.
>   MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: d0939ee2754c4c8d3626f629cc7e2dcc and found 99b8a9fd32ebcd8a33f312560ea4df78.

I tried it initially in Mars. Even that didn't work.
Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved It !!**

The problem was with my Network. It had a download limit of 150 MB, whereas, the plugin required around 250 MB. Once I removed the limit, there was no problem with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Juno is not supported by MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.
Use either Eclipse Kepler, Luna, or latest - Mars.

In Eclipse, go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and search for "mobilefirst", then install MobileFirst Studio.

Comment: Does it support Eclipse Mars 4.5.1?. Because I tried in that one too.

Comment: I have tried with v4.5.2 (Mars2, which is the latest). Installation passed successfully.

Comment: Do you think It might be due to network limitations?

Comment: Maybe. Try again later.